# Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributeText() on string

Tags: magento2, fatal-error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributeText() on string
>   in/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2_new/Sourcecode/app/design/frontend/Emthemes/em0150jewelry/jewelry/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml
>   on line 539.

This error occured by using a function
           `$optionText=$_product->getId()->getAttributeText('Farben');`

How can I resolve this in magento 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$_product->**getId()**->getAttributeText('Farben');
```

Maybe you mean check once

```
$_product->getAttributeText('Farben');
```

Comment: I get Notice: Undefined variable: _product with this code.